# mapStateToProps OwnProps argument contains a property that is undefined in Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am new react-redux user trying to connect a higher order component to react-redux store. In the map state to props function I am using ownProps argument for filtering the state. However, the property that I am trying to use within OwnProps is always undefined. Has anyone experienced something similar?

**Redux properties**

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { clearErrorAction } from "../features/errors/actions";
import { filterErrors } from "../features/errors/selectors";
import { FailureNotify } from "../features/errors/types";
import { HocComponentProps } from "./types";
import { RootState } from "typesafe-actions";

type StateProps = {
  error: FailureNotify[];
};

export const mapStateToProps = (
  state: RootState,
  ownProps: HocComponentProps
): StateProps => {
  // uniqueId property is always undefined here???
  console.log(`withErrorListener mapStateToProps => ${ownProps.uniqueId}`);
  return {
    error: filterErrors(state.errors as StateProps, ownProps)
  };
};

export const dispatchProps = {
  clearError: clearErrorAction
};

export const connector = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchProps
);
```

**The higher order component**

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { ConnectedProps } from "react-redux";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { connector } from "./redux";
import { FailureNotify } from "../features/errors/types";

/**
 * Type declarations
 */
type ReduxProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
type ExpectedProps = { uniqueId: string };

/**
 * Internal components
 */
type ErrorInfoProps = { info: FailureNotify } & ReduxProps &
  RouteComponentProps;
const ErrorInfo = ({
  info,
  clearError,
  history
}: ErrorInfoProps): JSX.Element => {
  function goHome(): void {
    console.log("Go home button has been clicked");
    clearError(info.fromAction, info.fromComponent, history, "/");
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Error {info.message}</p>
      <p>Received from action {info.fromAction}</p>
      <p>Received for component id {info.fromComponent}</p>
      <button onClick={goHome}>Home</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

/**
 * HoC that renders errors on the redux store rasied for a component.
 * @param BaseComponent  The component to wrap should have uniqueId property
 */
export const withErrorListener = <BaseProps extends ExpectedProps>(
  BaseComponent: React.ComponentType<BaseProps>
) => {
  /**
   * Type declarations
   */
  type HocProps = BaseProps & ReduxProps & RouteComponentProps;

  class ErrorListener extends React.Component<HocProps, {}> {
    static displayName = `withErrorListener(${BaseComponent.name})`;
    static readonly WrappedComponent = BaseComponent;

    /**
     * Render error if there is one to display, otherwise render the base component
     * @returns Rendered error if error occurred. Rendered base component if no error occurred.
     */
    render() {
      const { ...restProps } = this.props;
      console.log(`withErrorListener [error_count=${this.props.error.length}]`);
      if (this.props.error.length > 0) {
        return <ErrorInfo info={this.props.error[0]} {...restProps} />;
      } else {
        return <BaseComponent {...restProps as BaseProps} />;
      }
    }
  }

  const ConnectedHoc = connector(ErrorListener as any);
  const RoutedHoc = withRouter(ConnectedHoc as any);

  return RoutedHoc;
};
```

[image: Edit React Redux Typescript Nested Connected HoC Example - AttemptingToSolve]

I am creating an instance of the *withErrorListener* higher order component at the end of this [source file](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-attemptingtosolve-qfkr3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcontainers%2FPostsList.tsx&theme=dark)

```js
const PostsListConnectedWithId = connector(withId(PostsListBase));
export const PostsListWithErrorListener = withErrorListener(
  PostsListConnectedWithId
);
```

The source code for *PostsListBase* is available in the same [source file](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-attemptingtosolve-qfkr3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcontainers%2FPostsList.tsx&theme=dark)

*PostsListsWithErrorListener* is rendered in the [App](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-attemptingtosolve-qfkr3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApp.tsx&theme=dark) component.

The property that is always undefined is *uniqueId* and is injected  into the base component by the *withId* higher order component, [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-attemptingtosolve-qfkr3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fhigher-order-components%2FcomponentId%2FwithId.tsx&theme=dark). The console log output within the codesandbox shows the *uniqueId* property value.

Comment: Where and how are you actually rendering an instance of this HOC?

Comment: Thanks for comment, updated question with link to source file that instantiates the _withErrorListener_ HoC.

Comment: Can you show exactly where you're _rendering_ an instance of `<PostsListWithErrorListener>` ?

Comment: Thanks for comment, updated question with link to App component source file that renders PostsListWithErrorListener.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not actually passing in any IDs to that `<PostsListWithErrorListener>`, therefore `ownProps.uniqueId` won't exist.

Comment: Thanks or comment. I am trying to initialise the id property in another higher order omponent, ```const PostsListConnectedWithId = connector(withId(PostsListBase));```. I have updated the question with a link to the source code for the _withId_ higher order component.

Comment: Refactored the `withErrorListener` HoC to return withId Hoc that injects uniqueId property. If @markerikson would like to post an answer that uniqueId is not initialised then I will go ahead and accept his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working, after asking another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088446/experiencing-compile-error-with-a-higher-order-components-mapstate-function-tha).

The issue was a mixture of incorrectly connecting the HoC to redux store, i.e. component was casted to any. This issue was solved in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088446/experiencing-compile-error-with-a-higher-order-components-mapstate-function-tha).

One of the comments suggested that the uniqueId property was not being initialised. I refactored the withErrorListener HoC to inject the uniqueId property so that it is automatically assigned without the developer having to specify.

A codesandbox model can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/witherrorlistener-and-withid-hoc-components-the-version-that-compiles-207sg)

If the commenter wishes to suggest an answer that the uniqueId property was not initialised then I will accept it.